# Can total ascent be hard-coded into GPX, TCX or FIT files?

Tags: gpx, strava

Indoor workouts (including heart rate data) can be saved as GPX. The file can then be edited to hard-code total distance of the workout. Can total ascent also be saved in the file, or alternatively in the TCX or FIT formats allowed by Strava?

Comment: Question moved from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61117015/can-total-ascent-be-hard-coded-into-gpx-tcx-or-fit-files)

Comment: `Can total ascent also be saved in the file` Strict the answer will be yes, because even if it isn't there natively (I don't know) GPX is an XML schema, and the schema allows extensions ~ https://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd.  So probably you need to add more detail about how you might want to add the data and access the data.